# Subtracting one normal distribution from another

Tags: normal-distribution, arithmetic

This is a very simplistic question.

What is the resulting distribution of Norm(2,4) - Norm(1,3)? Is it Norm(2-1,sqrt(16+9)) = Norm(1,5)?

Additions are easy: Norm(0,3) + Norm(2,4) = Norm(2,5) (assuming we use sigma and not the variance as a second parameter)

However, I do not know about subtractions.

Is it Norm(1, sqrt(5)) ?

Thank you

Comment: The means add, and the variances add.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some intuition.  If $X$ is normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, then $-X$ is normally distributed with mean $-\mu$ but the same standard deviation $\sigma$.  This is because normal distributions are symmetric about their mean.

So if $X$ and $Y$ are independent normal random variables, then $Y - X = Y + (-X)$.  What does this imply for how $Y - X$ is distributed?

Comment: @Toly Are you saying that $N(2,4) + N(0,3) = N(2,5)$ but $N(2,4) + N(-1,3) = N(1,7)$? The point of this answer is that it turns a subtraction problem into an addition problem, which you say you already know about.

Comment: @ David K - Yes it is my question - SUBTRACTION Does Norm(2,4) - Norm(1,3) = Norm(1,5) - using sigma - not Var.

Comment: I think this answer is quite clear already: it says how to turn a subtraction into an addition. **That** is how you do subtraction. In your particular example, this answer says that $N(2,4) - N(1,3) = N(2,4) + N(-1,3).$ You should be able to answer for yourself what $N(2,4) + N(-1,3)$ is.